# Shortest code to repeat array([x,y,z]) in Python

Tags: python, numpy

What is the shortest code to repeat numpy `array([x,y,z])` and make `array([[x,y,z], [x,y,z], [x,y,z], ...])` which to make the code like shown below:

```
import numpy as np
p = np.array([1, 2, 3])
n = 10
p_n = np.tile(p, n).reshape(n, 3)
```

output of the code:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works pretty well. I don't see the point of shorten few characters.

That said here's a (few-character) shorter option

```
p_n = np.vstack([p]*n)
```

**Note**: avoid `from numpy import *`. Numpy has too many things and it may break some of Python's default functionalities (e.g. `bool`)

Comment: Your code is shorter than mine. and thanks to comment that we should be avoid `from numpy import *`. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

*If* you already have an array prepared which stores the repeated coordinates, then this is short enough:

```
p_n[:] = p
```

It's helpful if you assign to `p_n` multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `np.repeat`, for example

```
np.repeat(np.arange(3)[None,:],4,axis=0)
```

Comment: This works too. But it is difficult to remember how to write the slice code  `[None,:]` for me^^

Comment: You can add that dimension to `p` right at the start, `np.array([[1,2,3]]).repeat(n,0)`.  But using the `[None,:]` syntax should become familiar; it's very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Given array `p` and scaling number `n`, shortest one would be (without any function to help it make it a short one) -

```
p_n = p+[[0]]*n
```

Sample run -

```
In [17]: p+[[0]]*n
Out[17]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```